# osascript : automate several clicks in Xcode application doesn't work

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, xcode

I'd like to run ocascript from bash that goto my Xcode application and perform the following steps :

1. click the `Select All` button under `Edit` menu.
2. click the `Paste` button under `Edit` menu
   (this will replace my file with the new content from the clipboard)
3. click the `Save` button under `File` menu.

I've tried to do the following without much success, I only see the `Select all` being executed :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "aaa" | pbcopy

osascript <<EOF
activate application "Xcode"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Xcode"
click menu item "Select All" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
click menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
click menu item "Save" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
end tell 
EOF
```

Perhaps someone can help me fix this script ?

EDIT:
So apparently the only button I cannot reach is the `Edit->Paste->Paste` (see drawing attached) I already reached this item but couldn't click it somehow - here's the code I've used

```
osascript <<EOF
activate application "Xcode"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Xcode"
    click menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
    click menu item "Paste" of menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
end tell
EOF
```

but it fail in the final stage with reason :
`183:256: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Paste" of menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1 of process "Xcode". (-1728)`
any idea why ?

[image]

Comment: Select All, Paste, and Save are not buttons!

Comment: But they are clickable menu item, no ? and the `select all` option actually worked for me using the script above

Comment: RE: "But they are clickable menu item, no ?" --  Yes they are clickable but it doesn't make them buttons!  They are by `class` a `menu item` **not** a button.

Comment: You should probably read the _manual page_ for `osascript` as the `-e` _option_ takes one line of a script. Multiple `−e` _options_ may be given to build up a multi-line script. IMO passing the **AppleScript** _code_ to `osascript` is easier when done as a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: I've fixed my script. However, the problem with the paste remains

Comment: With a **Xcode** _document_ opened and having copied and pasted the _code_ in your question to an executable _shell script_ and then saved and run it, it does exactly what it's coded to do. You are going to have to provide additional details, enough so that we can attempt to reproduce your issue, whatever it is.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you time and comments. I've added an EDIT section with more detailed info about my specific problem.

Comment: You are using a different version of **Xcode** then I tested under, try using: `click menu item "Paste" of menu 1 of menu item "Paste" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1`